# I want to get the userId when the name is click in the spinner

Tags: binding, spinner

I want to get the userId when the name is click in the spinner. The array is as mention below.

```
       if(response.size()!=0)
       {
           for(MessageComposeDTO s : response)
           {
           System.out.println("contact list"+s.contactList);
           System.out.println("first name"+s.firstName);
           contactList1[ii] = s.contactList;
           firstName1[ii] = s.firstName;         
           ii++;
           }
       }
```

Comment: if you are getting the userId with the corresponding parrameter like firstName, contactList etc. then simply getting the clickable position of spinner you can abstract the corresponding value else you can use hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the firstName is click then get the item position of the array, then with the position access the item from contactList1.... as the item's are filled simultaneousness.